# Setting a Jersey response status code from interface without returning Response

Tags: java, hibernate, http, jersey

I am trying to set a response status of the following Jersey REST endpoint

```
@Path("/roles")
public interface IRoleService {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Role create(Role role);

}
```

Since it creates a new resource it would be appropriate if it returned Status code 201 but currently it returns 200.

The only way I found how to set the status code is to have the method return a `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` and set it there, but I really do not want all of my interfaces to return a generic Response instead of the actual response object (in this case `Role`).

Comment: From generic response object you can wrap any object and deserialise at client-side to get back the actual object. That is the beauty of making it generic. May I understand what are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: The idea is to have transparent interfaces so that you can be sure about what object actually arrives as the response. By wrapping it inside the Response object you lose that and you put additional constraints on the caller who has to expect wrong objects in the response body which he otherwise wouldn't need to if the interfaces were defined the way I have it.

Comment: I don't think this will make any difference. Either way, at client side you'll have to convert JSON object into POJO which requires you to specify the respective class object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to create a custom annotation and using a response filter to set the status. For example

**Annotation**

```
@NameBinding
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Status {
    int DEFAULT_CODE = 0;

    int code() default DEFAULT_CODE;
}
```

**ContainerResponseFilter**

```
@Status
@Provider
public class StatusFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo info;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext req, ContainerResponseContext res) throws IOException {
        Status status = getInterfaceAnnotation(info.getResourceMethod());
        if (status != null) {
            int code = status.code();
            if (code != Status.DEFAULT_CODE && res.getStatus() == 200) {
                res.setStatus(code);
            }
        }
    }

    private static Status getInterfaceAnnotation(Method resourceMethod) {
        String methodName = resourceMethod.getName();
        Class<?>[] paramTypes = resourceMethod.getParameterTypes();
        Class<?> iface = resourceMethod.getDeclaringClass().getInterfaces()[0];
        Method ifaceMethod;
        try {
            ifaceMethod = iface.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, paramTypes);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return ifaceMethod.getAnnotation(Status.class);
    }
}
```

In the filter, we get the method with `ResourceInfo` and do some reflection to get the `@Status` annotation. The from there, can grab the status code and set it on the response.

Since it is a Name Binding filter, it will only be called for methods that are annotated with it. See more [here](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html).

Then to use it, just add the annotation to the method.

```
public interface ITestResource {
    @GET
    @Status(code=201)
    String get();
}
```

The same could be done for headers if you need to add some custom headers.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I'm looking for, thank you.

Comment: @Paul Samsotha  Class<?> iface = resourceMethod.getDeclaringClass().getInterfaces()[0]; is giving index out of bound.

Answer (score 0):

```
Removed ElementType.Type.

    @NameBinding
    @Target({ElementType.METHOD})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface Status {
        int DEFAULT_CODE = 0;
        int code() default DEFAULT_CODE;
    }

statusFilter class:

    @Provider
    public class StatusFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

        private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StatusFilter.class);

        @Context
        private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

        @Override
        public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
            Status status = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getAnnotation(Status.class);
            if(status!=null){
                int code = status.code();
                if(code != Status.DEFAULT_CODE && responseContext.getStatus() == 200) {
                    responseContext.setStatus(code);
                }
            }
        }
    }

Then use it in the resource interface method declaration

@POST
@Status(code = 201)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
GetUserResponse createUser(UserRequest userRequest);
```