# Set Cookie in Jersey and still return Object

Tags: cookies, jersey, dropwizard

Is there a way to incorporate the type of the returned data in the return type of a Jersey resource method while still being able to set a cookie?

The problems are:

1. If using `Response.ok().cookie(...)`, then the return type of the method is `Response`, which breaks an attempt on the client side to deserialize it automatically using Jackson and obtaining a statically typed object representing the data.
2. If the method signature is `public MyClass get()`, then I haven't found a way to set the cookie.

I guess if the return type could be something like `Response<MyClass>` it would be fine.

Is there such a solution?

Comment: What does the resource method return type have to do with the client? Are you using some proxy client where you use interfaces? One solution would be to use a response filter.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha thanks for the comment. Yes I am using TeaVM, which enables to use an interface to specify which API endpoint to hit, and to use the returned value directly. I'll look at response filters. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49446798/2587435) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29954305/2587435). A combination of the two would be a good solution.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Thanks a lot! This is interesting! I guess I understand the basic principle, but I wonder how I could pass the cookie value to my filter. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Through the annotation. You can pass static values to the annotation. Then when you get the annotation in the filter, get the values from it. If you're not too familiar with using custom annotations, just go through some tutorials. It's pretty simple.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply! I saw how to pass static values, but the problem is that the cookie value is dynamic, and generated inside my resource method.

Comment: What specific values would you need inside the resource method?

Comment: What I mean is that the cookie value I need to set is generated inside my resource method. This resource method calls a service which generates a token, and I set this token as a cookie. Thus I would need the filter to receive that token in order to set it.

Comment: And this service can't be called from inside the filter?

Comment: Hmm, I'll think about it. It would be kind of weird though, because that would mean 100% of the work would be done in the filter, the resource itself would be useless

Comment: Ok, so I found out that you can just inject the `HttpServletResponse` into the implementation class (via field or constructor). You can add the cookie that way. Much easier.

Comment: Very interesting! I'll try it. This seems to be exactly what would solve the problem